# Oracle SQL query doesn't show correct value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I have a table with following columns:

- id
- technology
- name_event
- time_event

I count the number of values in a table with the following query

```
    select  1, 'Folder' as "Technology", 'Status' as "Name_Event", count(dm1.id) as "number of items", max(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20000101','yyyymmdd')+(SYSDATE - dm1.time_event),'hh24:mi:ss')) as "Time in system" 
    from db dm1 join db dm2 on dm1.id = dm2.id
    where dm1.technology = 'Folder' and dm1.name_event = 'status1' and NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM db dm2 WHERE dm2.name_event = 'status2' and dm2.id = dm1.id)
```

I did following inserts

```
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(1,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(2,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(3,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(4,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(5,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(6,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(7,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(8,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(9,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
    INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(10,'Folder', 'status1', 01:00:00);
INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(4,'Folder', 'status2', 02:00:00);
INSERT INTO DB(id, technology, name_event, time_event) VALUES(1,'Folder', 'status2', 03:00:00);
```

I inserted 10 rows in status 1 and moved 2 to status 2. So there should be 8 items in status 1 when I execute the query, but the result is 10...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about providing those 10 insert statements too along with the create table script?

Comment: Unless we have your sample data, it's going to be difficult for us to see what you're doing wrong - can you add the table definitions and the insert statements?

Comment: can you please provide some sample data in you table, then we can provide answer more quickly

Comment: are you running the insert, move commands and running the sql in same session ? if you don't do a commit and run the sql in other session it will still show the old value. * Just checking here.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the query? How did you move the values?

Comment: You just created two more entries instead of moving them via UPDATE. There are still 10 in status 1.

Comment: Update is impossible, because I need to keep the original rows.

Comment: Last `insert` has `status4`, if you change it to `status2` your query will show 8 as number of items.

Comment: changed it, but didn't make a difference.

Comment: But you probably didn't remove this row with status4. You can also change condition to `dm2.name_event <> 'status1'` instead of `dm2.name_event = 'status2'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you are `join`ing `dm2` but then using a `NOT EXISTS` correlated subquery (and using the same alias inside that subquery). I can't replicate the problem with my setup, but that could sure confuse something! So try without that second copy of db, and just keep the `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select  1, 'Folder' as "Technology", 'Status' as "Name_Event", count(dm1.id) as "number of items", max(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20000101','yyyymmdd')+(SYSDATE - dm1.time_event),'hh24:mi:ss')) as "Time in system" 
from db dm1 
where dm1.technology = 'Folder' and dm1.name_event = 'status1' and NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM db dm2 WHERE dm2.name_event = 'status2' and dm2.id = dm1.id)
```

Comment: What do you get if you do a `SELECT COUNT(*) from db dm1 
where dm1.technology = 'Folder' and dm1.name_event = 'status1'`? Or what about doing a `SELECT * FROM ...` - it seems others have equal difficulty recreating, which could suggest something funny going on in your data

Comment: at least it worked now by your code, I don't know why it didn't first, maybe a commit that needed to take place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 more inserts into the table, so now you have 10+2 total 12 inserts , to move data, use update statement.

```
update db set name_event='status2' where id=4;
update db set name_event='status4' where id=1;
```

Comment: I can't use an update because I need to keep my original rows ;-)

Comment: @Guil , can you pls elaborate on your requirements?  if you keep the original rows, you will end up with both the data, duplicate for id, else you can keep a trigger and move the data to another table which will hold the old data and this table will reflect the new changes

Comment: my requirements are that I make inserts when a status change happens.
After this I make a lot of analytics because it's a monitoring table.

Using a duplicate table is silly because in practise there are more than 10 states, but I simplify my problem.